# How do I join multiple glob inputs into a time lapse with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, mac, time-lapse

I'm trying to combine image files from multiple directories into one combined time lapse using ffmpeg, but when running this code, only the first directory is used in the time lapse. How do I combine multiple glob inputs using ffmpeg?

```
ffmpeg -pattern_type glob -i "Time\ Lapse\ 11/*.JPG" \
-pattern_type glob -i "Burst\ Sequence\ 5/*.JPG" \
-pattern_type glob -i "Burst\ Sequence\ 6/*.JPG" \
-r 30 -c:v libx264 -crf 23 -preset fast -pix_fmt yuv420p tl11_combined.mp4
```

I've tried using glob sequence which didn't do anything, so was wondering how to do this. Thanks!

Comment: pipe the three sequences in series to ffmpeg instead of reading it as three inputs. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/40872592

Comment: Is there any way to do this with glob though instead of individual file names? Each directory could have tons of files, so I'd rather do it with pattern matching than sequentially list all files.

Comment: Yes, you can use globbing, see my linked answer.

Comment: So if I'm understanding you, you want me to run
1. cat Time\ Lapse\ 11/*.JPG | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 24 -i - out.mp4
2. cat Burst\ Sequence\ 5/*.JPG | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 24 -i - out.mp4
3. cat Burst\ Sequence\ 6/*.JPG | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 24 -i - out.mp4

as 3 separate commands?

Comment: `cat "Time Lapse 11/*.JPG" "Burst Sequence 5/*.JPG" "Burst Sequence 6/*.JPG"  | ffmpeg -f image2pipe -framerate 24 -i - out.mp4`